# Get NGINX to serve .gz compressed asset files with unicorn

Tags: deployment, nginx, unicorn

I want activate gzip compression in my nginx and unicorn:

I have this in my rails app in **config/unicorn.rb:**

```
working_directory "/home/user/project.com/current"
shared_path  = '/home/user/project.com/shared'
pid "#{shared_path}/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.log"
listen '/tmp/unicorn.project.sock'
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
```

I have this in my **nginx.conf** in my rails app:

```
upstream unicorn {
 server unix:/tmp/unicorn.project.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

 server {
       listen 80 default;
       root ~/project.com/current/public;
       try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

       location @unicorn {
                           proxy_pass http://unicorn;
                         }
 error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

**How can I enable for this config sth like:**

```
  gzip_static on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to `server { }` block in your config:

```
location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
  root /path/to/public;
  gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Checkout [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have in my nginx.conf for gzip:

```
gzip on;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_min_length 0;
gzip_types text/plain text/css image/x-icon image/png image/jpg image/jpeg text/js text/php application/javascript application/x-javascript;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";
```

You can also log the gzip compression:

```
log_format main
        '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
        '"$gzip_ratio"';
```